# iOS Safari - disable zoom

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari, zooming

Im trying to disable a feature on mobile safari, but not really sure how to describe it.

I am adding in a Jquery slider which supports the `swipeleft()` and `swiperight()` touch events.

As such I want to disable the feature whereby when you swipe to the edge of a page, it shows the grey 'apple linen background' behind the site.

This is interfering with the user experience and I want to fix my site in the center, so the user cannot pull it around within the 'browser space'

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this inside your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: also add some css to avoid scrolling at screen flip: body {overflow:hidden; }